# Ionic 2: NavPop brings me to root rather than previous page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am having an issue with navigation in my app.  The page hierarchy works like so:

---

*Top*

- **VisitComponent** (non-tabbed)
- **CheckInPage** (non-tabbed)
- **ClientGenericPage** (tabbed)
- **HelloIonicPage** (non-tabbed)

*Root*

---

A standard flow of events would be:

1. Start at the **HelloIonicPage**
2. `push()` the **ClientGenericPage**
3. Select the tab corresponding to the **CheckInPage**
4. `push()` the **VisitComponent** from a button on the **CheckInPage**

The issue arises when I attempt to `pop()` from the **VisitComponent**.  I would expect to end up at the **CheckInPage** but instead I end up at the **HelloIonicPage** (root component).

When I call `this.navCtrl.getViews()` I see an array of 2 views: `[CheckInPage, VisitComponent]`.

I am really at a loss as to why I would end up at the root after calling `this.navCtrl.pop()`.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, the **ClientGenericPage** header was displayed on top of the **VisitComponent** header, and thus clicking back was firing the event on the parent, not the child.